# Does the sequence of the args matters when using gcc?

Tags: gcc

```
gcc  -o fig fig.c -I./include ./lib/libmylib.a -g

gcc -g  fig.c  -o fig -I./include ./lib/libmylib.a

gcc -g -o fig fig.c -I./include ./lib/libmylib.a
```

It seems that the gcc accept different kinds of sequence.
However, what is a not acceptable sequence? Does the sequence of arguments matters?

Comment: gcc's flags handling is similar to any modern linux command flags handling, nothing special.

Comment: You'd normally do compiling and linking in separate steps in your build system.

Comment: @Drakosha: That's not true. As you can see from the examples, it will accept intermingled options and arguments, which is really quite unusual.

Comment: Insofar as flags/arguments are fed into a state machine one after the other, the order always matters, even though the effects are not always as dramatic as in birryree's answer. For example `-Wall -Wno-reorder` and `-Wno-reorder -Wall` are different things. `-Ifoo -Ibar` and `-Ibar -Ifoo` may make several seconds of difference in compile speed, `-lfoo -lbar` or `-lbar -lfoo` where one uses symbols of the other may make a difference of _half an hour_ if you're unlucky, or fail (depending on linker flags), etc. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One sequence that does matter is where you put libraries if you specify `-static` linkage.

Basically, if you choose to statically link libraries in, the libraries should be specified after your code, as GCC will scan the code first for external library dependencies and then check the libraries to bring in. If you specified the libraries before the code that needs them, GCC would scan and determine no libraries were needed, and you'd end up with linker errors.

Comment: I just went through a lot of pain due to this error, and finally figured out it was due to the argument order.  Searching around, I found your answer, so thanks, in a parallel universe maybe-not-me-but-some-else sort of a way.