# What is the proper sequence of options for gcc & the importance of that sequence?

Tags: c, gcc

I used this command for compiling my program:

`gcc -g -Wall -Werror -lpthread multi_thread_server.c -o multi_thread_socket_v4`

It gave `undefined reference to <function_name>` error.

After of lot of trial and error to fix the error, finally I (by mistake) rearranged the options to `gcc` as:

`gcc multi_thread_server.c -lpthread -Wall -Werror -o multi_thread_server -g`

and it worked.

I read [this question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369125/does-the-sequence-of-the-args-matters-when-using-gcc), I got the reason as why it happened.

Here I want to know that, is there any rule for the sequence of options used for `gcc`?

P.S.: I know there are **infinite** options available for `gcc`, I want to know the sequence according to the category of options.

Comment: Rule is: Suppose `A` is a shared object which depends on `B` and `C` then order will be `A B C` while linking.

Comment: If you think of `gcc` as a compiler AND a linker (which it is), then generally you'd want to have compiler related options before linker related options. So your `.c` files and `-W` options would come before `-lxxx` and `-oxxx` options. Some may not matter (`-g`). At the very least, you'd want file information in that order (source files before lib files). I think in your case, the real issue was that your `.c` was initially after the `-lpthread`. The other options are probably fine since they aren't ambiguous relative to compiler or linker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List libraries last.

After compiling, GCC passes files to the linker for linking (unless linking is not to be performed, as happens when you request compilation-only with the `-c` switch). It passes the files to the linker in the order you list them (or their corresponding inputs) on the command line.

You listed `-lpthread` (which means the pthread library, named `libpthread.a` or something similar) followed by `multi_thread_server.c` (which gets compiled to an object file named `multi_thread_server.o`. So the linker receives the library first, then the object file.

When the linker processes a library file, it extracts from it **only** the modules that supply a definition of a symbol that is needed to satisfy earlier references to the symbol. Since the library is the first file, there are no earlier references. When the linker processes `multi_thread_server.o`, it sees the references, but it is too late; the linker does not go back to the library.

If you list `multi_thread_server.c` first, the linker will see `multi_thread_server.o` first, and it will see that it has unsatisfied referencs. Then, when the linker processes the library, it will find the definitions for those references and will extract those modules from the library.