# Can not link dbus with c++

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, dbus

I have simple program which includes dbus and uses basic functions e.g.:

```
 DBusError err;
 dbus_error_init(&err);
```

When I try to compile the program

```
g++ -Wall --std=c++11 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include  -ldbus-1 main.cpp
```

I get following errors:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `dbus_error_init'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `dbus_bus_get_private'
main.cpp:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `dbus_connection_set_exit_on_disconnect'
main.cpp:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `dbus_bus_request_name'
main.cpp:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `dbus_error_is_set'
main.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I do not understand it. I tried to compile similiar application but written in C and everything compiled and linked.

Comment: I think you need add -L option to indicate libraries

Comment: @Uday nope, it does not work

Comment: @Uday, `-L` option indicate path to library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `-l` options at the end:

```
g++ -Wall --std=c++11 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include main.cpp -ldbus-1
```

Here is related question: [What is the proper sequence of options for gcc & the importance of that sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388710/what-is-the-proper-sequence-of-options-for-gcc-the-importance-of-that-sequence)

This behaviour is expected and according to documentations:

`man g++`

> ...
>   You can mix options and other arguments.  For the most part, the order you use doesn't matter.  Order does matter when you use
>   several options of the same kind; for example, if you specify -L more
>   than once, the directories are searched in the order specified.  **Also, the placement of the -l option is significant.**
>   ...
>   -llibrary
>   ...
>   **It makes a difference where in the command you write this option**; the
>   linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
>   they are specified.  Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches library z after file foo.o but before bar.o.  If bar.o refers to functions in z, those functions may not be loaded.
>   ...