# undefined reference to '__gthrw___pthread_key_create(unsigned int*, void (*)(void*))

Tags: c++11, gcc, opensuse, gcc4.8

I'm using 64-bit gcc-4.8.2 to generate a 32-bit target, and my machine is 64-bit. I'm using c++11 concurrency features such as thread, mutex, conditiona_variables and etc.

The linker gave the above error message when trying to link the executable. libMyLib is also part of the project.

```
libMyLib.so: undefined reference to '__gthrw___pthread_key_create(unsigned int*, void (*)(void*))
```

nm libMyLib.so | grep pthread_key_create shows:

```
U _ZL28__gthrw___pthread_key_createPjPFvPvE
w __pthread_key_create@@GLIBC_2.0
```

where is the symbol 'ghtrw___pthread_key_create' from? I tried adding '-lpthread(-pthread)' as compiler flag, but it does not help.

More information. nm libMyLib.so | grep pthread shows other symbols such as _ZL20__gthread_mutex_lockP15pthread_mutex_t is defined

Comment: `I tried adding '-lpthread' as compiler flag` - are you aware about [correct options sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388710/what-is-the-proper-sequence-of-options-for-gcc-the-importance-of-that-sequence)?

Comment: Use the `-pthread` compiler flag instead.

Comment: Adding '-pthread' does not fix my problem. Still the question, where does missing symbol come from?

Comment: what is the target and does it have weak support? might be unrelated but gthr.h sets _GLIBCXX_GTHREAD_USE_WEAK to 0 for mingw32

Comment: Did you pass any `-I` flags during the compilation?

Comment: you need to copy/paste the exact compilation line of your *executable*, the fact that mylib.so has undefined symbols is meaningless (use ldd / readelf to check mylib points to pthread).

Comment: @malat it's a big project which uses cmake. I'll try to reproduce it with a minimal example

Comment: @user11869 just type `make VERBOSE=1` and copy/paste the compilation line for your exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where is the symbol 'ghtrw___pthread_key_create' from?

It is defined in GCC's "gthreads" abstraction layer for thread primitives, in the `gthr-posix.h` header.

```
#if SUPPORTS_WEAK && GTHREAD_USE_WEAK
# ifndef __gthrw_pragma
#  define __gthrw_pragma(pragma)
# endif
# define __gthrw2(name,name2,type) \
  static __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
  __gthrw_pragma(weak type)
# define __gthrw_(name) __gthrw_ ## name
#else
# define __gthrw2(name,name2,type)
# define __gthrw_(name) name
#endif

/* Typically, __gthrw_foo is a weak reference to symbol foo.  */
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)

...

#ifdef __GLIBC__
__gthrw2(__gthrw_(__pthread_key_create),
     __pthread_key_create,
     pthread_key_create)
```

After preprocessing that expands to:

```
static __typeof(pthread_key_create) __gthrw___pthread_key_create __attribute__ ((__weakref__("__pthread_key_create")));
```

It is supposed to be a weak reference to `__pthread_key_create`, so it should never have a definition, because it is just a reference to glibc's internal `__pthread_key_create` symbol.

So it looks like something has gone wrong with how you build you library. You should not have an undefined weak symbol.

Comment: Last time I saw this error was with another compiler (oracle) that does not define `__GNUC__`, so sys/cdefs defines `__attribute__(X)` as nothing (sunCC provides its own sys/cdefs to avoid this).

Comment: I checked that __GNUC__ is defined

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely, I found this from gcc documentation "If the target symbol is only referenced through weak references, then the becomes a weak undefined symbol." I don't quite understand the meaning of this sentence. But could this be the reason?

Comment: Yes, it could be, but I would expect `-lpthread` to resolve the reference. Is it possible you don't have a 32-bit libpthread.so installed on your system, so `-lpthread` gets ignored, and the weak reference is left unresolved?

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled into this error, and not because of a missing `-pthread`.

The situation happened in a somewhat unusual setup: I was compiling a software written in C++14 under Centos7. Since C++14 requires a recent version of GCC, I relied on [devtoolset 6](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-6/) for it.

Given the specific setup, I opened a thread on the Centos mailing list, so I'm directly referencing the relevant thread. See https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-devel/2018-May/016701.html and https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-devel/2018-June/016727.html

In short, it might be caused by some bug in the preprocessor macros, either of glibc or libgcc. It can be fixed by placing `#include <thread>` in the beginning of the source code which gives problems once compiled. Yes, even if you don't use `std::thread` in it.

I don't claim this will work for everyone, but it might do the job in some particular situations.