# gcc 4.8 does not find reference in .so library

Tags: gcc, hyperlink, compilation, shared-libraries

I wrote a .so lib in x.c:

```
int x() { return 0; }
```

And compile it as:

```
gcc -o libx.so --shared -fPIC x.c
```

Then I made a program in main.c:

```
extern int x();
int main() { return x(); }
```

Then compile as:

```
gcc -o main -L. -lx main.c
```

It always report error:

```
xxx.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `x'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, it works with gcc 4.1.2 and 4.4. Anybody know why?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
gcc -o main main.c -L . -lx
```

Instead of:

```
gcc -o main -L. -lx main.c
```

It works for me:

`$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.`
`$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
`$ ./main`
`$`

Related questions:
- [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388710/what-is-the-proper-sequence-of-options-for-gcc-the-importance-of-that-sequence);
- [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369125/does-the-sequence-of-the-args-matters-when-using-gcc).